# How to get a TextArea font size in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I use below method to get the font size from a TextArea object:

```
String fontSize = getTextArea().getElement().getAttribute("fontSize");
```

but it returns an empty string. How can I get a textarea font size in GWT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
getTextArea().getElement().getStyle().getFontSize();
```

This will work as long as there is a fontsize set for the text area.

Comment: I got an empty string. Is there a default font size for a text area?

Comment: I believe that the default font size should be 16px

Comment: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp) **Note:** _If you do not specify a font size, the default size for normal text, like paragraphs, is 16px (16px=1em)._